# Windows showing different max SSD space then bios

Tags: ssd, disk-space

I have inherited an AData 256GB ssd. Bios confirmed this is 256GB. Windows Explorer is showing 499MB of max space (364 KB free). I am wondering how come Windows Explorer is showing only 499MB? How would I access the remaining ~255GB from Windows?

Note that Windows is installed on this ssd. My future plan is to get the Windows product key, somehow do a fresh install of Windows, and use this ssd on another computer.

Comment: What does the partitionmanager show?

Comment: Haha, I didn't realize the ssd was split into several partitions. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

mashuptwice suggested that I used Partition Manager which showed the drive being split up into multiple partitions.